# How to connect to more than one Cosmos DB using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, azure

Here are my files:

**application.yml**

```
azure:
  cosmos:
    uri: ${COSMOS_URI:https://localhost:8081}
    key: ${COSMOS_KEY:...}
    database: ${COSMOS_DB:courses-service}
```

**CosmosService.java**

```
@Service
public class CosmosService {

    private final RepoCosmos cosmos;

    public CosmosService(final RepoCosmos repoCosmos) {
        this.cosmos = repoCosmos;
    }

    public CourseCosmos saveCourse(final CourseCosmos courseCosmos) {
        cosmos.save(CourseCosmos);
        return courseCosmos;
    }

    public Optional<CourseCosmos> getCourse(final String id) {
        return cosmos.findById(id);
    }

    public void deleteById(final String id, final String partitionKey) {
        cosmos.deleteById(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
    }
}
```

**RepoCosmos.java**

```
@Repository
public interface RepoCosmos extends CosmosRepository<CourseCosmos, String> {
}
```

**CourseCosmos.java**

```
@Container(containerName = "courses", ru = "400")
public class CourseCosmos {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    @PartitionKey
    private String courseStatus;

    private String courseName
    
    // getters setters

}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to connect my project to a second database. Somewhere along the lines of:

```
azure:
  cosmos:
    uri: ${COSMOS_URI:https://localhost:8081}
    key: ${COSMOS_KEY:...}
    database1: ${COSMOS_DB:computing-courses-service}
    database2: ${COSMOS_DB:medical-courses-service}
```

When I try and google this, I'm not getting the results I'm expecting.

**EDIT:28/07/2021**

After further research I found this:
https://maanvi.medium.com/multi-cosmosdb-configuration-in-springboot-546c55d8d64

Connecting to more than one Cosmos Database appears to be relatively new to the Spring Boot library; which is probably why I'm having trouble finding examples.

Does anyone have a working example of connecting to more than one Cosmos DB using Spring Boot?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Question updated; I'm trying to figure out how to connect my project to a second database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with Cosmos.

- Split the repositories into packages according to different databases.
- Create different per-database persistence configuration

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases